# Cisco routers connected to firewall and switches, tests to see if they work?

Tags: networking

[I asked this question a few days ago and got a good answer.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13718/1-pix-firewall-2-routers-2-switches-please-answer-a-couple-questions-about-ha#comment21527_13718)

I have my routers, firewall, and switched connected.   How can I do some tests to see if this is all actually working.

I have a console port(rj45 to db9) but not db9 to usb so I can't hook it up to my comp.  I am assuming that this stuff should just work and it's just for a project so it doesn't need to actually be set up in any special way.  I will be getting a db9 to usb within the next couple days.

this is my set up router -> firewall -> switch1(office comps) -> switch2(dmz)

I might change this up to something similar to other answers.

edit:  the light went from orange to green at the end, where the last switch is, and I did a ipconfig /all and got this:  (usually isn't this):

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 2C-27-D7-B3-DB-EB
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3534:2e69:aca4:fca6%11(Preferred)
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.252.166(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 237774807
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-D4-66-81-2C-27-D7-B3-DB-EB
```

Success, or false flag?

Comment: this is actually just a basic networking question, so I will migrate to superuser.

Comment: Hello Hal - welcome to SuperUser.  It is difficult to understand from the above what your question actually is.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

All that ipconfig output is showing you is that the router is not providing a DHCP address (the 169... address is the internal default generated on your macine when it has a network connection and expects a DHCP address but doesn't get given one)

You will need to be able to log onto the router to see what is set up in terms of routing, controls, dhcp, protocols etc